# How to find the width and height of the label on a node in d3 and dagre-d3

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, d3.js, dagre-d3

I've been working for a while to get the width and height of a label from a d3 node. I have an icon on the node that will toggle a subGraph. But I need the node's width and height to be set dynamically based on the size of the label. Once I get the width of the label I can then make room for the icon. Label sizes may change so I need to know the width. Here is what I have, I am using dagre-d3 to position and render the nodes:

```
 nodes = [
   {id: 1, shape: "diamond", label: "Start"}
  ]

 for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    g.setNode(nodes[i].id, {
     label: nodes[i].label
      width: // I want to set the width here based on the width of the   label
    });
}
```

Been struggling with this any help is greatly appreciated. Happy to show more code if needed.

UPDATE:

Here is what I am doing to get the text of each node:

```
 svgGroup.selectAll("tspan").each(function (object:any) {

      object = parseInt(object, 10) // gives me the id of each node
      var nodeObject = g.node(object); // get the full node 
      var length = this.getComputedTextLength();
      for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
                if (node[i].id === object) {
                     // add the node label width to the nodes array
                     nodes[i].labelWidth = length; 
                  }
          }
 }
```

The above allows me to set the width of the node based on the label + toggle icon. The one problem I'm having is if a node has a sub graph I'm noticing that "svgGroup.selectAll("tspan")" is only getting the top level nodes. For example, my nodes look like this:

```
  this.nodes = [

      {id: 1, shape: "ellipse", label: "start", 
         subGraph: {
               nodes = [
                    {id: 10, shape: "ellipse", label: "SubNode1"},
                    {id: 11, shape: "ellipse", label: "SubNode2"}
                ],
                edges = [
                     {from: 10, to: 11, type: "vee", label: ""}
                 ]
              }
           },
      {id: 2, shape: "rect", label: "Square"}
  ]
```

The "svgGroup.selectAll" statement only gets the tspan for the top nodes with id 1 and id 2. Is there a way to get the tspan for the subGraph nodes of id 10 and id 11. Because id 10 or 11 could potentially have a subGraph nested within it, if thats the case I need to get the label width for those nodes as well.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14569745/1675954

Comment: Thanks Rachel, that helped. I'm finding that the "svgGroup.selectAll" statement is only getting the first set of nodes. My graph may contain subGraphs. In that case I need to get the tspan label width of those nodes as well, is there a way to write that selectAll statement to get nested tspans as well? I've updated my answer above

Comment: i note you didn't upvote the answer :( but i'll consider helping you further after a few hours sleep (its 5am now - i'm in France)

Comment: i think you could consider using the d3 forced layout see this link http://www.d3noob.org/2013/03/d3js-force-directed-graph-example-basic.html  must sleep now