# Get width of text node in d3 inside .attrs method

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have added some text nodes using d3 as below.

```
svg.selectAll('text.label')
    .data(studentTable, d => d.name)
    .enter()
    .append('text')
    .attrs({
      class: 'label',
      x: d => x(d.value),
      y: d => y(d.rank),
    })
```

Now in transition i need to access the width of the currently selected text node and set the x position according to the width. (See the comments of below code snippet).

```
svg.selectAll('.label').data(studentTable, d => d.name)
        .transition()
        .duration(tickDuration)
        .ease(d3.easeLinear)
        .attrs({
          x: d => x(d.value), // Here i need to get the width of current text node to set x position
          y: d => y(d.rank)
        });
```

Any convenient way to do this ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method for getting the text length is `getComputedTextLength()`, which you have to use with the node. To get the text node inside the arrow function, use the third and second arguments combined. So:

```
.attrs({
    x: (d, i, n) => n[i].getComputedTextLength() + whatever, 
    y: d => y(d.rank)
});
```

Here is a demo using your code, the red line shows the end of the text:

```js
const svg = d3.select("svg");
svg.selectAll('text.label')
  .data([{
    value: 100,
    rank: 50
  }])
  .enter()
  .append('text')
  .attrs({
    class: 'label',
    x: d => d.value,
    y: d => d.rank,
  })
  .text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet");
  
svg.append("line")
  .attr("x1", 100 + svg.select(".label").node().getComputedTextLength())
  .attr("x2", 100 + svg.select(".label").node().getComputedTextLength())
  .attr("y1", 0)
  .attr("y2", 100)
  .style("stroke", "red");

svg.selectAll('.label')
  .data([{
    value: 100,
    rank: 50
  }])
  .transition()
  .delay(1000)
  .duration(1000)
  .ease(d3.easeLinear)
  .attrs({
    x: (d, i, n) => d.value + n[i].getComputedTextLength(),
    y: d => d.rank
  });
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="100"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-selection-multi.v1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: As mentioned in the [docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/v3.0.0/README.md#selection_attr), we could also use `this`, instead of `n[i]`, to get the current node. However, that only works with `function ()`, *not* with arrow functions `() =>`, as discussed [here](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/issues/97).