# SVG: how to replace <html:div> tag by <svg:text> tag to display a tooltip (rectangle width is variable)?

Tags: html, d3.js, svg, tooltip

I have created a HTML page containing a SVG image.
In this page, I have created a custom tooltip that is a `<html:div>`.

I have currently read that current browsers are now able to read SVG file.
So I have decided to migrate my HTML file to SVG file.

All work correctly. Styles and Javascript continue to work with SVG file.

One problem is remainding.

I have replaced `<html:div>` by one `<rect>` followed by one `<text>` SVG element like this

```
<rect id='tooltip-rect' x='20' y='20' width='200' height='25' fill='yellow'/>
<text id='tooltip-text' x='20' y='20' dominant-baseline='middle' text-anchor='start'>
    Tooltip: ?
</text>
```

I have written some javascript so when mouse is moving over an  image the tooltip text find just below `<use>` tag in a `<desc>` SVG tag is copied in `<text id='tooltip'>`.

```
<use href='#interrupteur' x='3540' y='410'/>
<desc class='info'>
interrupteur sur le mur de séparation cuisine/sàm
</desc>
```

Javascript code used to display tooltip

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 

var tooltip = d3.select("#tooltip-text");
var toolrec = d3.select("#tooltip-rect");

d3.select("svg").selectAll("use")
    .on("mouseover", function ()
        {
        var sTooltip = "";

        var e = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (e != null)
            {
            if (e.className.baseVal == "info")
                {
                sTooltip = e.innerHTML;
                }
            }

        if (sTooltip == "")
            {
            sTooltip = this.href.baseVal;
            }

        if (sTooltip == "")
            {
            sTooltip = "? Tooltip";
            }

        document.getElementById('tooltip-text').innerHTML = sTooltip;
        tooltip.style("opacity", "1");
        toolrec.style("opacity", "1");
        })
    .on("mousemove", function ()
        {
        toolrec.attr("x", d3.select(this).attr("x") - 4);
        toolrec.attr("y", d3.select(this).attr("y") - 12);
        tooltip.attr("x", d3.select(this).attr("x"));
        tooltip.attr("y", d3.select(this).attr("y"));
        })
    .on("mouseout", function ()
        {
        tooltip.style("opacity", "0");
        toolrec.style("opacity", "0");
        return true;
        });

});
```

That works ... but

In HTML, the width of rectangle that bound text tooltip is growing when text is larger and is reducing when text is shorter.

In SVG solution, the size or rectangle remains fix.

[image: electrical plan displaying tooltip on Chrome]

In previous image, the text is too long and is overlapping rectangle !

What can I do so that width of  is dependant of tooltip's length as in HTML `<div>` solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to my problem.

I compute the length of `<text>` element that is containing the tooltip's text using D3 `getComputedTextLength()` function. 
Thanks to [https://stackoverflow.com/a/14569745/948359](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSSjN.png)

Then I use this length to fix the width of `<rect>` that contains `<text>` tooltip.

Using this technic, I have now tooltip when dragging mouse over some device.

[image: Electrical schema with tooltip]

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 

var tooltip = d3.select("#tooltip-text");
var toolrec = d3.select("#tooltip-rect");
var iTextLength = 0;

d3.select("svg").selectAll("use")
    .on("mouseover", function ()
  {
  var sTooltip = "";
  
        var e = this.nextElementSibling;
     if (e != null)
         {
      if (e.className.baseVal == "info")
          {
             sTooltip = e.innerHTML;
                }
            }
  
        if (sTooltip == "")
            {
            sTooltip = this.href.baseVal;
            }

        if (sTooltip == "")
            {
            sTooltip = "? Tooltip";
            }

        tooltip.node().innerHTML = sTooltip;
  iTextLength = tooltip.node().getComputedTextLength();
  tooltip.style("opacity", "1");
  toolrec.style("opacity", "1");
  })
    .on("mousemove", function ()
  {
        toolrec.attr("x", d3.select(this).attr("x") - 5);
        toolrec.attr("y", d3.select(this).attr("y") - 12);
        toolrec.attr("width", iTextLength + 10);
        tooltip.attr("x", d3.select(this).attr("x"));
        tooltip.attr("y", d3.select(this).attr("y"));
  })
    .on("mouseout", function ()
  {
        tooltip.style("opacity", "0");
        toolrec.style("opacity", "0");
  return true;
  });

});
```

```css
:root {
    --line-color: black;
    --line-width: 2;
    }

line, polyline, rect, circle, path {
    stroke-width: var(--line-width);
    stroke: var(--line-color);
    }

#tooltip-text {
    max-width: 800px;
    text-align:left;
    transition: opacity 0.4s;
    pointer-events:none;
    opacity: 0;
    padding: 4px;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 14;
 }
 
#tooltip-rect {
    background: yellow;
    border:solid gray;
    max-width: 800px;
    transition: opacity 0.4s;
    pointer-events:none;
    opacity: 0;
 }

svg {
    margin:10px 20px;
    overflow:visible; 
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.5.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="2.0" width="8000px" height="6000px">
  <defs>
    <g id="differentiel">
      <rect x="-5" y="0" width="40" height="40" style="opacity:0" />
      <g transform="rotate(-20,0,0)">
        <polyline points="0 0 0 40 5 40 5 35 0 35" fill="none" />
      </g>
    </g>
    <g id="disjoncteur" transform="rotate(-20,0,0)">
      <polyline points="0 0 0 40 5 40 5 35 0 35" fill="none" />
    </g>
    <g id="prise">
      <path d="m40,-20 a20,20 0 0,0 0,40 z" fill="white" style="stroke:white" />
      <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="20" y2="0" />
      <line x1="20" y1="-15" x2="20" y2="15" />
      <path d="m40,-20 a20,20 0 0,0 0,40" fill="none" />
      <line x1="40" y1="-20" x2="40" y2="-28" />
      <line x1="40" y1="20" x2="40" y2="28" />
    </g>
    <g id="connexion">
      <rect x="0" y="-10" width="20" height="20" fill="white" />
    </g>
    <g id="lampe">
      <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="15" stroke="none" style="opacity:0" />
      <line x1="-10" y1="-10" x2="10" y2="10" />
      <line x1="10" y1="-10" x2="-10" y2="10" />
    </g>
    <g id="interrupteur">
      <circle cx="10" cy="0" r="10" fill="white" />
      <g transform="rotate(-60 10 0)">
        <line x1="20" y1="0" x2="50" y2="0" />
      </g>
    </g>
    <g id="int-sans-fil">
      <rect x="0" y="-5" width="10" height="10" fill="white" />
    </g>
    <g id="int-wifi">
      <rect x="0" y="-5" width="10" height="10" fill="white" />
    </g>
    <g id="int-radio">
      <rect x="0" y="-5" width="10" height="10" fill="white" />
    </g>
    <g id="int-unipolaire">
      <circle cx="10" cy="0" r="10" fill="white" />
      <g transform="rotate(-60 10 0)">
        <line x1="20" y1="0" x2="50" y2="0" />
        <line x1="50" y1="0" x2="50" y2="5" />
      </g>
    </g>
    <g id="int-bipolaire">
      <circle cx="10" cy="0" r="10" fill="white" />
      <g transform="rotate(-60 10 0)">
        <line x1="20" y1="0" x2="50" y2="0" />
        <line x1="50" y1="0" x2="50" y2="5" />
        <line x1="45" y1="0" x2="45" y2="5" />
      </g>
    </g>
    <g id="int-va-et-vient">
      <circle cx="10" cy="0" r="10" fill="white" />
      <g transform="rotate(-60 10 0)">
        <line x1="20" y1="0" x2="50" y2="0" />
        <line x1="50" y1="0" x2="50" y2="5" />
        <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="-30" y2="0" />
        <line x1="-30" y1="0" x2="-30" y2="-5" />
      </g>
    </g>
    <g id="inverseur">
      <g transform="translate(w²²0 0)">
        <circle cx="10" cy="0" r="10" fill="white" />
        <g transform="rotate(-60 10 0)">
          <line x1="20" y1="0" x2="50" y2="0" />
          <line x1="50" y1="0" x2="50" y2="5" />
          <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="-30" y2="0" />
          <line x1="-30" y1="0" x2="-30" y2="-5" />
        </g>
        <g transform="rotate(60 10 0)">
          <line x1="20" y1="0" x2="50" y2="0" />
          <line x1="50" y1="0" x2="50" y2="-5" />
          <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="-30" y2="0" />
          <line x1="-30" y1="0" x2="-30" y2="5" />
        </g>
      </g>
    </g>
    <g id="machine-à-laver">
      <rect x="0" y="-20" width="40" height="40" fill="white" fill-opacity="0.0" />
      <circle cx="20" cy="0" r="12" stroke="blue" fill="none" />
      <circle cx="20" cy="0" r="5" stroke="blue" fill="red" />
    </g>
    <g id="séchoir">
      <rect x="0" y="-20" width="40" height="40" fill="white" fill-opacity="0.0" />
      <circle cx="15" cy="-8" r="5" fill="none" />
      <circle cx="25" cy="-8" r="5" fill="none" />
      <circle cx="20" cy="8" r="5" fill="black" />
    </g>
    <g id="chauffe-eau">
      <circle cx="20" cy="0" r="20" fill="white" fill-opacity="0.0" />
      <circle cx="20" cy="0" r="15" fill="cyan" />
      <path d="m5,0 l 5,-5 l 10,10 l 10,-10 l 5,5" fill="none" />
    </g>
    <g id="chauffe-eau-direct">
      <circle cx="20" cy="0" r="20" fill="cyan" />
      <path d="m0,0 l 5,-5 l 10,10 l 10,-10 l 10,10 l 5,-5" fill="none" />
    </g>
    <g id="télérupteur">
      <rect x="0" y="-10" width="40" height="20" fill="white" />
      <path d="m5,5 h10 v-10 m20,10 h-10 v-10" fill="none" />
    </g>
    <g id="télérupteur-radio">
      <rect x="0" y="-10" width="40" height="20" fill="none" />
      <path d="m5,5 h10 v-10 m20,10 h-10 v-10" fill="none" />
      <path d="M25,15 A5,5 0 0,1 15,15" fill="none" stroke-width="1" />
      <path d="M30,15 A10,10 0 0,1 10,15" fill="none" stroke-width="1" />
      <path d="M35,15 A15,15 0 0,1 5,15" fill="none" stroke-width="1" />
    </g>
    <g id="télérupteur-wifi">
      <rect x="0" y="-10" width="40" height="20" fill="none" />
      <path d="m5,5 h10 v-10 m20,10 h-10 v-10" fill="none" />
    </g>
    <g id="bouton-poussoir">
      <circle cx="10" cy="0" r="10" fill="none" />
      <circle cx="10" cy="0" r="5" fill="red" />
    </g>
    <g id="transformateur">
      <circle cx="10" cy="0" r="10" fill="none" />
      <circle cx="20" cy="0" r="10" fill="none" />
    </g>
    <g id="lave-vaisselle">
      <rect x="0" y="-20" width="40" height="40" fill="white" />
      <line x1="0" y1="-20" x2="40" y2="20" />
      <line x1="0" y1="20" x2="40" y2="-20" />
      <circle cx="20" cy="0" r="10" fill="white" />
    </g>
    <g id="plaque-cuisson">
      <rect x="0" y="-20" width="40" height="40" fill="white" />
      <circle cx="30" cy="-10" r="5" stroke="blue" fill="none" />
      <circle cx="30" cy="10" r="5" stroke="blue" fill="none" />
      <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="5" stroke="blue" fill="none" />
    </g>
    <g id="télévision">
      <rect x="0" y="-20" width="60" height="40" fill="white" />
      <rect x="5" y="-15" width="50" height="30" fill="none" />
      <line x1="30" y1="20" x2="30" y2="25" />
      <line x1="20" y1="25" x2="40" y2="25" />
    </g>
    <g id="ordinateur">
      <rect x="0" y="-20" width="40" height="30" fill="white" />
      <rect x="5" y="-15" width="30" height="20" fill="none" />
      <rect x="0" y="15" width="40" height="10" fill="none" />
      <line x1="20" y1="20" x2="35" y2="20" />
    </g>
    <g id="four-classique">
      <rect x="0" y="-20" width="40" height="40" fill="white" />
      <line x1="0" y1="-10" x2="40" y2="-10" />
      <circle cx="20" cy="5" r="5" fill="none" />
    </g>
    <g id="four-pyrolyse">
      <rect x="0" y="-20" width="40" height="40" fill="white" />
    </g>
    <g id="micro-onde">
      <rect x="0" y="-20" width="40" height="40" fill="white" fill-opacity="0.0" />
      <g transform="scale(0.2 0.2)">
        <path d="M20 -30 C 40 -80 , 80 -80 , 100 -30 S 160 30, 180 -30" stroke="black" fill="none" />
        <path d="M20   0 C 40 -50 , 80 -50 , 100   0 S 160 50, 180   0" stroke="black" fill="none" />
        <path d="M20  30 C 40 -20 , 80 -20 , 100  30 S 160 80, 180  30" stroke="black" fill="none" />
      </g>
    </g>
    <g id="frigo">
      <rect x="0" y="-20" width="40" height="40" fill="white" />
      <text x="20" y="6" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" font-size="24">*</text>
    </g>
    <g id="congélateur">
      <rect x="0" y="-20" width="40" height="40" fill="white" />
      <text x="20" y="4" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle">***</text>
    </g>
    <g id="radiateur">
      <rect x="0" y="-15" width="60" height="30" fill-opacity="0.0" />
      <path d="m0,0 l5,0 l 5,-10 l 10,20 l 10,-20 l 10,20 l 10,-20 l 5,10 l5,0" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" />
    </g>
    <g id="volet">
      <rect x="0" y="-20" width="40" height="40" fill-opacity="0.0" />
      <path d="M0,-15 h 40 M0,-10 h 40 M0,-5 h 40 M0,0 h 40 M0,5 h40" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" />
    </g>
    <g id="spot">
      <path d="m10,-10 a10,10 0 0,0 0,20" fill="none" />
      <circle cx="10" cy="0" r="5" fill="yellow" />
      <g transform="rotate(-45,10,0)">
        <line x1="5" y1="0" x2="15" y2="0" stroke-width="1" />
        <line x1="10" y1="-5" x2="10" y2="5" stroke-width="1" />
      </g>
    </g>
    <g id="neon-simple">
      <line x1="0" y1="-5" x2="0" y2="5" stroke="black" />
      <line x1="40" y1="-5" x2="40" y2="5" stroke="black" />
      <rect x="0" y="-2" width="40" height="4" fill="yellow" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" />
    </g>
    <g id="neon-double">
      <line x1="0" y1="-7" x2="0" y2="7" stroke="black" />
      <line x1="40" y1="-7" x2="40" y2="7" stroke="black" />
      <rect x="0" y="-6" width="40" height="4" fill="yellow" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" />
      <rect x="0" y="2" width="40" height="4" fill="yellow" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" />
    </g>
    <g id="compteur">
      <rect x="0" y="-20" width="40" height="40" fill="none" />
      <line x1="0" y1="-10" x2="40" y2="-10" />
      <text x="20" y="5" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" font-family="Arial" font-size="16">kWh</text>
    </g>
  </defs>

<line x1='100' y1='50' x2='100' y2='90'/>
<text x ='110' y='70' fill='black' font-family='Arial' font-size='20'>Différenciel PRINCIPAL</text>
<text x ='110' y='100' fill='black' font-family='Arial' font-size='12'>&#x0394;300 mA</text>
<use href='#differentiel' x='100' y='90'/>
<line x1='100' y1='130' x2='100' y2='170'/>
<line x1='100' y1='170' x2='100' y2='210'/>
<text x ='110' y='190' fill='black' font-family='Arial' font-size='20'>B</text>
<text x ='110' y='220' fill='black' font-family='Arial' font-size='12'>10A</text>
<use href='#differentiel' x='100' y='210'/>
<desc class='info'>
B: éclairage Etage + Cave  + Hall + WC + cagibi +
</desc>
<line x1='100' y1='250' x2='100' y2='330'/>
<text x='90' y='334' fill='black' font-family='Arial' font-size='16' text-anchor='end'>B1</text>
<line x1='100' y1='330' x2='120' y2='330'/>
<use href='#int-va-et-vient' x='120' y='330'/>
<desc class='info'>
hall: interrupteur à droite des escaliers
</desc>
<use href='#int-va-et-vient' x='140' y='330'/>
<desc class='info'>
hall: interrupteur à gauche de la porte de la cuisine
</desc>
<line x1='160' y1='330' x2='200' y2='330'/>
<use href='#lampe' x='200' y='330'/>
<desc class='info'>
lampe Hall dans l'entrée
</desc>
<line x1='100' y1='330' x2='100' y2='410'/>
<text x='90' y='414' fill='black' font-family='Arial' font-size='16' text-anchor='end'>B7</text>
<line x1='100' y1='410' x2='120' y2='410'/>
<use href='#int-unipolaire' x='120' y='410'/>
<desc class='info'>
chambre Est: interrupteur à gauche de la porte
</desc>
<line x1='140' y1='410' x2='180' y2='410'/>
<use href='#lampe' x='180' y='410'/>
<desc class='info'>
lampe chambre Est (Musson)
</desc>
<line x1='100' y1='410' x2='100' y2='490'/>
<text x='90' y='494' fill='black' font-family='Arial' font-size='16' text-anchor='end'>B8</text>
<line x1='100' y1='490' x2='120' y2='490'/>
<use href='#int-va-et-vient' x='120' y='490'/>
<desc class='info'>
interrupteur à gauche de l'escalier
</desc>
<line x1='140' y1='490' x2='170' y2='490'/>
<use href='#inverseur' x='170' y='490'/>
<desc class='info'>
interrupteur à droite du passage entre caves
</desc>
<line x1='190' y1='490' x2='220' y2='490'/>
<use href='#int-va-et-vient' x='220' y='490'/>
<desc class='info'>
interrupteur à droite de la porte de garage
</desc>
<line x1='240' y1='490' x2='280' y2='490'/>
<use href='#lampe' x='280' y='490'/>
<desc class='info'>
lampes cave petit garage
</desc>
<line x1='100' y1='490' x2='100' y2='570'/>
<text x ='90' y='574' fill='black' font-family='Arial' font-size='16' text-anchor='end'>B12</text>
<line x1='100' y1='570' x2='120' y2='570'/>
<use href='#télérupteur-radio' x='120' y='570'/>
<use href='#int-radio' x='140' y='610'/>
<use href='#int-radio' x='160' y='610'/>
<use href='#int-radio' x='180' y='610'/>
<line x1='160' y1='570' x2='200' y2='570'/>
<use href='#lampe' x='200' y='570'/>
<desc class='info'>
lampe couloir étage Ouest (Signeulx)
</desc>
<line x1='100' y1='170' x2='350' y2='170'/>
<line x1='350' y1='170' x2='350' y2='210'/>
<text x ='360' y='190' fill='black' font-family='Arial' font-size='20'>C</text>
<text x ='360' y='220' fill='black' font-family='Arial' font-size='12'>25A</text>
<use href='#differentiel' x='350' y='210'/>
<desc class='info'>
C: triphasé cuisine
</desc>
<line x1='350' y1='250' x2='350' y2='330'/>
<text x ='340' y='334' fill='black' font-family='Arial' font-size='16' text-anchor='end'>C1</text>
<line x1='350' y1='330' x2='370' y2='330'/>
<use href='#connexion' x='370' y='330'/>
<desc class='info'>
connection directe
</desc>
<line x1='390' y1='330' x2='410' y2='330'/>
<line x1='410' y1='330' x2='430' y2='330'/>
<use href='#four-classique' x='430' y='330'/>
<desc class='info'>
four Siemens
</desc>
<line x1='350' y1='330' x2='350' y2='410'/>
<text x ='340' y='414' fill='black' font-family='Arial' font-size='16' text-anchor='end'>C2</text>
<line x1='350' y1='410' x2='370' y2='410'/>
<use href='#connexion' x='370' y='410'/>
<desc class='info'>
connection directe
</desc>
<line x1='390' y1='410' x2='410' y2='410'/>
<line x1='410' y1='410' x2='430' y2='410'/>
<use href='#micro-onde' x='430' y='410'/>
<desc class='info'>
micro-onde Siemens
</desc>
<line x1='350' y1='170' x2='530' y2='170'/>
<line x1='530' y1='170' x2='530' y2='210'/>
<text x ='540' y='190' fill='black' font-family='Arial' font-size='20'>Différentiel SECONDAIRE</text>
<text x ='540' y='220' fill='black' font-family='Arial' font-size='12'>&#x0394;30 mA</text>
<use href='#differentiel' x='530' y='210'/>
<line x1='530' y1='250' x2='530' y2='290'/>
<line x1='530' y1='290' x2='530' y2='330'/>
<text x ='540' y='310' fill='black' font-family='Arial' font-size='20'>E</text>
<text x ='540' y='340' fill='black' font-family='Arial' font-size='12'>16A</text>
<use href='#differentiel' x='530' y='330'/>
<desc class='info'>
E: éclairage et 2 prises dans salle de bain principale
</desc>
<line x1='530' y1='370' x2='530' y2='450'/>
<text x='520' y='454' fill='black' font-family='Arial' font-size='16' text-anchor='end'>E1</text>
<line x1='530' y1='450' x2='550' y2='450'/>
<use href='#int-unipolaire' x='550' y='450'/>
<desc class='info'>
interrupteur à gauche de la colonne de descente d'eau
</desc>
<line x1='570' y1='450' x2='610' y2='450'/>
<use href='#lampe' x='610' y='450'/>
<desc class='info'>
lampe salle de bain
</desc>
<line x1='530' y1='450' x2='530' y2='530'/>
<text x ='520' y='534' fill='black' font-family='Arial' font-size='16' text-anchor='end'>E2</text>
<use href='#prise' x='530' y='530'/>
<desc class='info'>
bloc prises à gauche de la colonne de descente d'eau
</desc>
<use href='#prise' x='550' y='530'/>
<desc class='info'>
bloc prises à gauche de la colonne de descente d'eau
</desc>
<line x1='530' y1='290' x2='680' y2='290'/>
<line x1='680' y1='290' x2='680' y2='330'/>
<text x ='690' y='310' fill='black' font-family='Arial' font-size='20'>F</text>
<text x ='690' y='340' fill='black' font-family='Arial' font-size='12'>16A</text>
<use href='#differentiel' x='680' y='330'/>
<desc class='info'>
F: Salle-de-bain ETAGE + prise TV + prise PC bureau
</desc>
<line x1='680' y1='370' x2='680' y2='450'/>
<text x ='670' y='454' fill='black' font-family='Arial' font-size='16' text-anchor='end'>F1</text>
<use href='#prise' x='680' y='450'/>
<desc class='info'>
prise TV au Salon
</desc>
<line x1='680' y1='450' x2='720' y2='450'/>
<line x1='720' y1='450' x2='740' y2='450'/>
<use href='#télévision' x='740' y='450'/>
<desc class='info'>
TV Philips
</desc>
<line x1='680' y1='450' x2='680' y2='530'/>
<text x ='670' y='534' fill='black' font-family='Arial' font-size='16' text-anchor='end'>F2</text>
<use href='#prise' x='680' y='530'/>
<desc class='info'>
prise PC au Bureau
</desc>
<line x1='680' y1='530' x2='720' y2='530'/>
<line x1='720' y1='530' x2='740' y2='530'/>
<use href='#ordinateur' x='740' y='530'/>
<desc class='info'>
ordinateur Dell
</desc>
<line x1='680' y1='530' x2='680' y2='610'/>
<text x ='670' y='614' fill='black' font-family='Arial' font-size='16' text-anchor='end'>F3</text>
<line x1='680' y1='610' x2='700' y2='610'/>
<use href='#télérupteur-radio' x='700' y='610'/>
<use href='#int-radio' x='720' y='650'/>
<line x1='740' y1='610' x2='780' y2='610'/>
<use href='#lampe' x='780' y='610'/>
<desc class='info'>
Salle-de-bain: lampe plafond
</desc>
<line x1='680' y1='610' x2='680' y2='690'/>
<text x ='670' y='694' fill='black' font-family='Arial' font-size='16' text-anchor='end'>F4</text>
<use href='#prise' x='680' y='690'/>
<desc class='info'>
Salle-de-bain: lampe meuble
</desc>
<line x1='680' y1='690' x2='680' y2='770'/>
<text x ='670' y='774' fill='black' font-family='Arial' font-size='16' text-anchor='end'>F5</text>
<use href='#prise' x='680' y='770'/>
<desc class='info'>
Salle-de-bain: prise radiateur
</desc>
<line x1='680' y1='770' x2='720' y2='770'/>
<line x1='720' y1='770' x2='740' y2='770'/>
<use href='#radiateur' x='740' y='770'/>
<desc class='info'>
radiateur Jaga
</desc>
<line x1='680' y1='770' x2='680' y2='850'/>
<text x ='670' y='854' fill='black' font-family='Arial' font-size='16' text-anchor='end'>F6</text>
<use href='#prise' x='680' y='850'/>
<desc class='info'>
Salle-de-bain: bloc de prises sous le meuble
</desc>
<use href='#prise' x='700' y='850'/>
<desc class='info'>
Salle-de-bain: bloc de prises sous le meuble
</desc>
<line x1='680' y1='290' x2='860' y2='290'/>
<line x1='860' y1='290' x2='860' y2='330'/>
<text x ='870' y='310' fill='black' font-family='Arial' font-size='20'>G</text>
<text x ='870' y='340' fill='black' font-family='Arial' font-size='12'>16A</text>
<use href='#differentiel' x='860' y='330'/>
<desc class='info'>
G: Salle-de-bain PRINCIPALE + Bloc machines à laver
</desc>
<line x1='860' y1='370' x2='860' y2='450'/>
<text x ='850' y='454' fill='black' font-family='Arial' font-size='16' text-anchor='end'>G1</text>
<use href='#prise' x='860' y='450'/>
<desc class='info'>
bloc de prises à l'évier
</desc>
<use href='#prise' x='880' y='450'/>
<desc class='info'>
bloc de prises à l'évier
</desc>
<line x1='860' y1='450' x2='860' y2='530'/>
<text x ='850' y='534' fill='black' font-family='Arial' font-size='16' text-anchor='end'>G2</text>
<use href='#prise' x='860' y='530'/>
<desc class='info'>
lampe meuble
</desc>
<line x1='860' y1='530' x2='860' y2='610'/>
<text x ='850' y='614' fill='black' font-family='Arial' font-size='16' text-anchor='end'>G3</text>
<use href='#prise' x='860' y='610'/>
<desc class='info'>
bloc de prises au petit garage à gauche de l'évier
</desc>
<use href='#prise' x='880' y='610'/>
<desc class='info'>
bloc de prises au petit garage à gauche de l'évier
</desc>
<use href='#prise' x='900' y='610'/>
<desc class='info'>
bloc de prises au petit garage à gauche de l'évier
</desc>
<use href='#prise' x='920' y='610'/>
<desc class='info'>
bloc de prises au petit garage à gauche de l'évier
</desc>
<line x1='920' y1='610' x2='960' y2='610'/>
<line x1='960' y1='610' x2='980' y2='610'/>
<use href='#machine-à-laver' x='980' y='610'/>
<desc class='info'>
machine à laver
</desc>
<line x1='530' y1='170' x2='1080' y2='170'/>
<line x1='1080' y1='170' x2='1080' y2='210'/>
<text x ='1090' y='190' fill='black' font-family='Arial' font-size='20'>I</text>
<text x ='1090' y='220' fill='black' font-family='Arial' font-size='12'>16A</text>
<use href='#differentiel' x='1080' y='210'/>
<desc class='info'>
I: chambre étage Ouest (Signeulx)
</desc>
<line x1='1080' y1='250' x2='1080' y2='330'/>
<text x ='1070' y='334' fill='black' font-family='Arial' font-size='16' text-anchor='end'>I1</text>
<use href='#prise' x='1080' y='330'/>
<desc class='info'>
prise à gauche de la porte
</desc>
<line x1='1080' y1='330' x2='1080' y2='410'/>
<text x ='1070' y='414' fill='black' font-family='Arial' font-size='16' text-anchor='end'>I2</text>
<use href='#prise' x='1080' y='410'/>
<desc class='info'>
prise radiateur en dessous de la fenêtre
</desc>
<line x1='1080' y1='410' x2='1120' y2='410'/>
<line x1='1120' y1='410' x2='1140' y2='410'/>
<use href='#radiateur' x='1140' y='410'/>
<desc class='info'>
radiateur Siemens
</desc>
<line x1='1080' y1='410' x2='1080' y2='490'/>
<text x ='1070' y='494' fill='black' font-family='Arial' font-size='16' text-anchor='end'>I3</text>
<line x1='1080' y1='490' x2='1100' y2='490'/>
<use href='#connexion' x='1100' y='490'/>
<desc class='info'>
volet chambre étage Ouest
</desc>
<line x1='1120' y1='490' x2='1140' y2='490'/>
<line x1='1140' y1='490' x2='1160' y2='490'/>
<use href='#volet' x='1160' y='490'/>
<desc class='info'>
volet
</desc>
<line x1='1080' y1='490' x2='1080' y2='570'/>
<text x ='1070' y='574' fill='black' font-family='Arial' font-size='16' text-anchor='end'>I4</text>
<use href='#prise' x='1080' y='570'/>
<desc class='info'>
bloc de prises à gauche de la paque de cuisson en vitrocéramique
</desc>
<use href='#prise' x='1100' y='570'/>
<desc class='info'>
bloc de prises à gauche de la paque de cuisson en vitrocéramique
</desc>
<use href='#prise' x='1120' y='570'/>
<desc class='info'>
bloc de prises à gauche de la paque de cuisson en vitrocéramique
</desc>
<line x1='1080' y1='170' x2='1260' y2='170'/>
<line x1='1260' y1='170' x2='1260' y2='210'/>
<text x ='1270' y='190' fill='black' font-family='Arial' font-size='20'>J</text>
<text x ='1270' y='220' fill='black' font-family='Arial' font-size='12'>16A</text>
<use href='#differentiel' x='1260' y='210'/>
<desc class='info'>
J: Prises bloc de cuisson
</desc>
<line x1='1260' y1='250' x2='1260' y2='330'/>
<text x ='1250' y='334' fill='black' font-family='Arial' font-size='16' text-anchor='end'>J1</text>
<use href='#prise' x='1260' y='330'/>
<desc class='info'>
bloc de prises à droite de la plaque de cuisson en vitrocéramique
</desc>
<use href='#prise' x='1280' y='330'/>
<desc class='info'>
bloc de prises à droite de la plaque de cuisson en vitrocéramique
</desc>
<use href='#prise' x='1300' y='330'/>
<desc class='info'>
bloc de prises à droite de la plaque de cuisson en vitrocéramique
</desc>
<rect id='tooltip-rect' x='20' y='20' width='100' height='25' fill="yellow"/>
<text id='tooltip-text' x='20' y='20' dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="start">
Tooltip: ?
</text>
</svg>
```